# Oracle.DataAccess.dll for .NET 4.0 in 32 bit Oracle Client install?

Tags: .net, oracle, enterprise-library, odp.net, gac

Below are two paths and the files present in the installation of Oracle client 32 bit (win32_11gR2_client.zip) for .NET 2.X and 4.X.  When I installed the Oracle client, I chose not to take the default in two of the windows during the Install Wizard.  I chose to install the "Runtime" and I also changed the install path from c:\apps{user}\ to c:\oracle because our Oracle DBA at my organization gave me those instructions.

C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\OraProvCfg.exe

C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4\
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe

I'm interested in referencing Oracle.DataAccess.dll assembly in a .NET 4.X application.  I found these instructions to add the dll file to the GAC for the 64 bit installation.

http://devblog.rayonnant.net/2011/04/oracle-11g-r2-x64-client-with-odac.html

Four questions.

1.) If I run this command (which I modified slightly for the path I have), for my 32 bit installation, what will happen?

```
cd C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4

OraProvCfg.exe /action:gac /providerpath:C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

2.) How can I get a list of the contents in the GAC before I run #1?

3.) Is this the correct command to undo #1?

```
cd C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4

OraProvCfg.exe /action:ungac /providerpath:C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

4.) Rather than adding it to the GAC, how can I generate the dll file instead?  What is the correct "action" argument for that?  The reason I'd like to do this is because I was not able to see the dll in the "4" folder.  I only saw the dll in the "2.x" folder.

Here is the help contents of this file if interested.

> C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4>OraProvCfg.exe
>
> Oracle Providers for .NET Configuration Utility for .NET Framework 4 :
>   Release 4 .112.3.0 Production on Thu Jul 23 12:09:37 2015 Copyright
>   (c) 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>
> Usage: OraProvCfg  /action:
>               [/force]
>               [/product:]
>               [/component:]
>               [/productversion:]
>               [/frameworkversion:<.NET framework version>]
>               [/providerpath:]
>               [/verbose:]
>               [/log:]
>
> Example: Installing an assembly in the GAC:
>       OraProvCfg  /action:gac  /providerpath:
>
> Example: Uninstalling an assembly from the GAC:
>       OraProvCfg  /action:ungac  /providerpath:
>
> ```
> Assembly name can be specified as "Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.5.10"
> to uninstall a specific version of assembly.
> ```
>
> Example: Configuring machine.config for ODP.NET:
>       OraProvCfg  /action:config  /product:odp  /frameworkversion:v2.0.50727
>                   /providerpath:
>
> ```
> OraProvCfg  /action:config  /force /product:odp
>             /frameworkversion:v2.0.50727
>             /providerpath:<Oracle.DataAccess.dll full path>
> ```
>
> Example: Unconfiguring machine.config for ODP.NET:
>       OraProvCfg  /action:unconfig  /product:odp  /frameworkversion:v2.0.50727
>
> Example: Registering ODP.NET Performance Counters:
>       OraProvCfg  /action:register  /product:odp  /component:perfcounter
>                   /providerpath:
>
> Example: Unregistering ODP.NET Performance Counters:
>       OraProvCfg  /action:unregister  /product:odp  /component:perfcounter
>                   /providerpath:
>
> Example: Configuring ODP.NET OraclePermission for Web Applications:
>       OraProvCfg  /action:config  /product:odp /component:oraclepermission
>                   /frameworkversion:v2.0.50727
>                   /providerpath:
>
> ```
> OraProvCfg  /action:config  /product:odp /component:oraclepermission
>             /frameworkversion:v2.0.50727
>             /productversion:<Oracle.DataAccess.dll product version>
> ```
>
> Example: Unconfiguring ODP.NET OraclePermission for Web Applications:
>       OraProvCfg  /action:unconfig  /product:odp  /component:oraclepermission
>                   /frameworkversion:v2.0.50727
>                   /providerpath:
>
> ```
> OraProvCfg  /action:unconfig  /product:odp  /component:oraclepermission
>             /frameworkversion:v2.0.50727
>             /productversion:<Oracle.DataAccess.dll product version>
> ```
>
> Example: Configuring machine.config for ASP.NET:
>       OraProvCfg  /action:config  /product:aspnet  /component:
>                   /frameworkversion:v2.0.50727
>                   /providerpath:
>
> ```
> OraProvCfg  /action:config  /force /product:aspnet
>             /component:<provider name>
>             /frameworkversion:v2.0.50727
>             /providerpath:<Oracle.Web.dll full path>
>
> <provider name> valid values: all, membership, profile, rolemanager,
> personalization, webevent, sitemap or a combination thereof
> ("membership | profile", for example). Default value is all.
> ```
>
> Example: Unconfiguring machine.config for ASP.NET:
>       OraProvCfg  /action:unconfig  /product:aspnet  /component:
>                   /frameworkversion:v2.0.50727
>
> ```
> <provider name> valid values: all, membership, profile, rolemanager,
> personalization, webevent, sitemap or a combination thereof
> ("membership | profile", for example). Default value is all.
> ```
>
> C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That "gac" action depends on the file already existing in the file (providerpath is the input file for this command).  So it didn't even run.

I had to download the odp.net package separately from the oracle site.

> ODAC112040Xcopy_32bit.zip (53MB)

And then I referenced the dll from here, since it wasn't included in the oracle client 32 bit install (win32_11gR2_client.zip).

```
C:\Users\{user}\Downloads\ODAC112040Xcopy_32bit\odp.net4\odp.net\bin\4\
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the providers, in Powershell:

```
[System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactoryClasses()
```